# Yii cgridview dataprovider error

Tags: php, yii

I have 2 models vseq and rseq.  I am trying to use a dataprovider from a rseq sql statement on a vseq view.  When I place the cgridview on the vseq page the page goes blank but doesn't give me any specific errors.  When I take it off the page renders fine.

Here is the code from my Rseq model:

```
public function getReceipts($patno){
$sql = " SELECT rseq.rdate AS receiptDate, rseq.ramount AS receiptAmount, rseq.rtype AS     receiptType, rseq.rcomment AS receiptComment
             FROM  rseq
             INNER JOIN vseq 
             ON rseq.rno = $patno
             LIMIT 500
    ";

    $connection=Yii::app()->db;
    $command=$connection->createCommand($sql);
    $dataReader=$command->query(); 
    $result=$dataReader->readAll();

    return $result;
}
```

And here is the code from my Vseq view:

```
$vpatNo = Vseq::model()->getPatient($vseqNo);
$test = $vpatNo['0']['vnum'];

$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'rseq-grid',
'dataProvider'=>Rseq::model()->getReceipts($test),
//'filter'=>$model,
'columns'=>array(
    //'ID',
    //'vlinevnum',
    //'vlinelineno',
    //'vlinefromdate',
    'receiptDate',
    array(
        'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
    ),
),
));
```

Is there something I am missing, I can't seem to figure out these data providers.

Comment: Also I have tested the SQL statement in phpMyAdmin and it works just fine there.

Comment: In your getReciepts function you need to return the CSqlDataProvider object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Must use [CArrayDataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CArrayDataProvider)

In Rseq model:

```
public function getReceipts($patno){
    $sql = " SELECT rseq.rdate AS receiptDate, rseq.ramount AS receiptAmount, rseq.rtype AS     receiptType, rseq.rcomment AS receiptComment
             FROM  rseq
             INNER JOIN vseq 
             ON rseq.rno = $patno
             LIMIT 500
    ";

    $resultAll =Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll();
    return new CArrayDataProvider($resultAll);
}
```

Comment: I am still getting a blank screen using this method.

Comment: This solution worked, the problem lied with another piece of code. Thanks.